Thread Safety of boost::cirularbuffer with non-consuming readers
I try to understand if I have a case where I need locking and at what place this is not thread-safe.
I have a relatively large buffer (say 300k elements). I have a producer who creates 1 datapoint each millisecond. On the other side I have a reader who starts at the newest value and then reads all new values every 10ms. But it just reads from the buffer, it does not pop. So the producer is expected to overwrite after 300k ms but due to the size of the buffer we do not expect to enter the readers position.
So my reduced example would be this:
  int i = 0;
  boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(1000);

  // simulate producer is already running for some time
  while(i < 50)
    cb.push_back(i++);

  std::jthread producer{[&i, &cb](){
    while(true) {
        cb.push_back(i++);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
  }};
  
  auto prev_last = cb.cend()-1;
  while(true) {

    // wait for buffer to fill
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

    // get the last valid element
    auto last_elem = cb.cend()-1;

    // iterate from where we stopped last time
    for(auto elem = prev_last; elem != last_elem; ++elem) {
        fmt::print("read: {}\n", *(elem));
    }
    
    // store end of this iteration
    prev_last = last_elem;
  }

more detailed example on godbolt
From what I read in the docs:

If multiple threads access a single circular_buffer, and at least one of the threads may potentially write, then the user is responsible for ensuring mutual exclusion between the threads during the container accesses.

it might not be thread-safe. But why?

What is the question here? This code is not thread-safe because it is not designed to be. There exist race conditions where read operations return invalid data if a write operation is performed simultaneously. To fix this, you need to manually provide mutual execution logic.

It sounds to me like you just want a more low-level datastructure. More like several circular-buffers mounted on the same shared memory, in a clever way that avoids synchronization requirements. It sounds like the only time-sensitive thing could be an atomic "producer head" offset. If you also specify how the buffer is initialized this could well have completely specified behavior, as long as you can guarantee the timing it depends on.

There is boost::spsc_queue for your use case. Why are you not using it?

Most containers have some sort of linking between nodes, moving elements around, updating some internal data -- whatever the container needs. So, if a thread modifies such data while another thread is reading it -- boom.
STL containers in general are not thread-safe by design: they follow the principle that if you WANT thread-safety, you can just do it yourself. They won't add it just because someone might need it -- and, sometimes, a threadsafe container is not enough anyway, so even if the container were threadsafe, people might still have to put more threadsafety around it...
